# Access interface property misunderstanding

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I'm developing an app and have an interface

```
export class MyInterface {
     Title: string;
}
```

I have an object of that interface "myInterface", in the view I'd like to access this title by calling

```
{{ myInterface.Title }}
```

But I can't do that. Angular forces me to call property with lowercase

```
{{ myInterface.title }}
```

**Why is so?**

Comment: could you please add the error message to your question ?

Answer (score 1):

An interface is only an assertion your code makes, that the object complies to this interface, to be used by tools like linters and autocompletion. 
It doesn't make the object actually comply to the interface.

Interfaces in typescript are dropped at runtime and are development-time only.

Comment: so interface compiles into javascript object with camelCase notation?

Comment: No, interface doesn't compile at all to JavaScript. Create your object with an uppercase `Title` property, than you can use it this way.

Comment: I have title in upper case, but can't access with upper case from template - http://screencast.com/t/jbGyQoXB7

Comment: As I said in my answer. Using the interface here is just to ensure to your tools that the object looks that way. If it doesn't actually look that way, the interface won't help you at all. You need to show the code that creates the object instance to point out the actual mistake.

Comment: Please have a look at this code - http://screencast.com/t/I8gOcOhr. In the interface I have "uppercased" first char of each property. But on html I can access this vis lowercase only..

Comment: If you want it to have an uppercase `Title` property, you need ensure the server sends the JSON that way. The interface is **just telling** your IDE that it can assume the object has one property named `Title`, but if at runtime the object is created differently, this `<IWeekStats>` is meaning less. `<IWeekStats>` **doesn't have any influence on the behavior of your application**, it only has influence what errors your IDE can show you and what autocompletion options your IDE will show you.

Comment: You shouldn't forget, even though you have types and all in TypeScript, at runtime it's still just JavaScript.

Comment: Oh :) My service sends property in lowercase. But Angular binds this to uppercase property. For me it's quite wired :) Is it normal behaviour?

Comment: It's JavaScript in the end. "weird" here is equivalent to "normal" in other languages ;p. Seriously, as I said, it's just information to your tools and not supposed to influence the runtime behavior of your application in any way. Therefore, yes this is normal behavior. Actually, I don't know what you mean by "Angular binds this to uppercase property". To my understanding this is what your question is about - that Angular can't bind to the uppercase property.